# If f is Riemann Integrable, then the lower sums tend to the integral.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

The title may be a bit confusing so here's what I'm trying to establish:

Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be Riemann integrable and let $\{P_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of partitions with $\lim_{k \to \infty} |P_k| = 0$. Prove that $\lim_{k \to \infty} L(f,P_k) = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \ dx$.

---

Proof Attempt:

Let $\{T_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of associated evaluation sets. Then, by the sequential definition of Riemann Integrability:

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} R(f,P_k,T_k) = I$$

We will attempt a direct method of proof. So, consider:

$$|L(f,P_k)-I| = |L(f,P_k)-R(f,P_k,T_k)+R(f,P_k,T_k) - I| \leq |L(f,P_k)-R(f,P_k,T_k)| + |R(f,P_k,T_k)-I|$$

It is easy to find some kind of bound on $|R(f,P_k,T_k)-I|$. So, we only worry about $|L(f,P_k)-R(f,P_k,T_k)|$. For $k \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$P_k = \{x_0 ^{(k)} = a < x_1 ^{(k)} < \ldots,x_{n_k} ^{(k)} = b \}$$

$$T_k = \{t_1 ^{(k)},t_2 ^{(k)},\ldots, t_{n_k} ^{(k)} \}$$

Then, we can write out:

$$L(f,P_k) = \sum_{i=1}^{n_k} m_{i} ^{(k)} \Delta x_i ^{(k)}$$

$$R(f,P_k,T_k) = \sum_{i=1}^{n_k} f(t_i ^{(k)}) \Delta x_i ^{(k)}$$

$$R(f,P_k,T_k)-L(f,P_k) = \sum_{i=1}^{n_k} \left(f(t_i ^{(k)})-m_i ^{(k)} \right) \Delta x_i ^{(k)}$$

$$R(f,P_k,T_k)-L(f,P_k) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n_k} \left(f(t_i ^{(k)})-m_i ^{(k)} \right) |P_k|$$

Since $f$ is Riemann Integrable, it is bounded so it has a supremum $M$ and an infimum $m$ on the interval $[a,b]$. Hence

$$|R(f,P_k,T_k)-L(f,P_k)| \leq |P_k| \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n_k} 2M = 2Mn_k |P_k|$$

This is where I'm quite stuck now because I don't know how to use this to bound the quantity on the left-hand side. Can someone give me a hint on how I can continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will point out before starting that in some sense this is the easy direction to prove because the initial definition of Riemann integrability is so *a priori* strong even though it is ultimately equivalent to the Darboux definition.

Anyway, you used too much brute force in passing to the global bound on $f$ in the last step. Your last RHS is actually guaranteed to not go to zero because $n_k |P_k| \geq b-a$.

Instead, you need to argue that $|f(t_i^{(k)})-m_i^{(k)}|$ can be made small by suitable choice of $t_i^{(k)}$: specifically, you really would like it to be at most  $\frac{\epsilon_k}{\Delta x_i^{(k)}}$ where $\epsilon_k$ is your favorite sequence of positive numbers going to zero. If you had that, then you would be done. But you do have that, by the definition of infimum.

Comment: Oh my gosh, so frustrating, I can't believe I didn't get that